# Retry an async function if the error is retryable

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

How can I change my logic to retry if the err.retryable = true in the following code:

```
async.each(queues, function (queue, callback) {
    sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, function (err, qurl) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.retryable) {
                // How to retry  sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}...?
            } else {
                console.error(err, err.stack);
                callback(err);
            }
        }else{
            //Do lots of things here
        }        

    })
}, function (err) {
    //...
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give queue callback a name and provide it in retry request again. Try this:

```
async.each(queues, function (queue, callback) {
    sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, function queueCallback(err, qurl) {
        if (err) {
            if (err.retryable) {
                sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, queueCallback);
            } else {
                console.error(err, err.stack);
                callback(err);
            }
        } else {
            //Do lots of things here
        }
    });
}, function (err) {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Thanks man, by "queueCallback" do you mean "callback"? (I mean the callback of async.each?)

Comment: No, I mean `sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, function queueCallback(err, qurl) { ...`. you can name callback function in `sqs.getQueueUrl`.

Comment: But there is lots of code inside function queueCallback(err, qurl) { and in this case I have duplicate code? (If I understood correctly!); by duplicate code I mean both in if (err.retryable) {
                sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, function queueCallback(err, qurl) { //Duplicate of Do lots of things here and else {
            //Do lots of things here
        }

Comment: No, you don't duplicate anything at all. You just need to give a name to callback function `queueCallback` and then just use this name `sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, queueCallback);`.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the advice by dfsq to name your callback and use it an asynchronously recursive manner, see also [async.retry](https://github.com/caolan/async#retry) from the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#readme) module by Caolan McMahon. Example:

```
async.retry(3, apiMethod, function(err, result) {
    // do something with the result
});
```

More complex example:

```
async.auto(
  {
    users: api.getUsers.bind(api),
    payments: async.retry(3, api.getPayments.bind(api))
  }, function(err, results) {
    // do something with the results
  }
);
```

More details [in the docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#retry).

## UPDATE

### A better solution for your use case:

I wrote a utility function that you can use to make your original method support any number of retries (with `err.retryable` support).

You can use it this way:

```
var retryingFunction = withRetries(sqs, sqs.getQueueUrl);
```

(Note that you need to provide **both** `sqs` **and** `sqs.getQueueUrl`)

And now you can use the `retryingFunction` just like you would use `sqs.getQueueUrl` but with a number of retries as the first arguments. The retries will only be done when `err.retryable` is true.

So now, instead of:

```
sqs.getQueueUrl({'QueueName': queue.queue}, function (err, qurl) {
  // ...
});
```

you can use:

```
retryingFunction(3, {'QueueName': queue.queue}, function (err, qurl) {
  // ...
});
```

where 3 is the number of retries.

And this is the function that I wrote to make the above possible:

```
function withRetries(obj, method) {
  if (!method) {
    method = obj;
    obj = null;
  }
  if (typeof method != "function") {
    throw "Bad arguments to function withRetries";
  }
  var retFunc = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var retries = args.shift();
    var callback = args.pop();
    if (typeof retries != "number" || typeof callback != "function") {
      throw "Bad arguments to function returned by withRetries";
    }
    var retryCallback = function (err, result) {
      if (err && err.retryable && retries > 0) {
        retries--;
        method.apply(obj, args);
      } else {
        callback(err, result);
      }
    };
    args.push(retryCallback);
    method.apply(obj, args);
  };
  return retFunc;
}
```

See this [**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/dafaso/3/edit?js,console) to play with it and see how it works.

It works fine in the demo, I hope it will also work for your code.

Comment: Yes! That sounds good! But How can I check the err.retryable in async.retry?

Comment: That retries just 3 times irrespective of error type! right?

Comment: @user3421904 You are right that what I originally wrote would retry 3 times irrespective of error type so I wrote a better solution. It is even simpler to use and supports `err.retryable` with any number of retries that you want. See my updated answer. I hope it works for you.